# How to dump data into MongoDB using flipkart/snapdeal affiliation API

Tags: json, mongodb

I would like to store the data of Flipkart and Snapdeal using Affiliate API into mongoDB.
Both API vendor provides data in json format.

Demo : http://affiliate.flipkart.com/api-docs/af_prod_ref.html#search-query-based-on-keywords-api

But I don't know how to do this.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If the response from those links is of type `json`, the in a bash shell you can do

```
curl "http://affiliate.flipkart.com/api-docs/af_prod_ref.html#search-query-based-on-keywords-api" | mongoimport -d <dbname> -c <collname>
```

Make sure to add other options to `curl` like authentication if required.

As an example, I used one of the public APIs and it imported the post into my post collection.

```
curl -k "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1" | mongoimport -c posts
```